# How to get dynamic value of a button click in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I asked this question moments back, which does not seems to help me out yet.

here it is: [How to pass dynamic data in bootstrap modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003452/how-to-pass-dynamic-data-in-bootstrap-modal/41003718#41003718)

This is what I am trying to achieve.

I click on the button which has a dynamic id everytime. Once I click on this button, modal opens up. Now I am performing some actions like file upload inside this modal (you can see the  submit tag in modal body). Now to do that, I need to get that dynamic id into this particular button attribute.

I know this sounds a bit confusing. but any way to get around this thing would be of great help.

Comment: It would be great if you could create a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that shows your current situation so we can get a better understanding of your problem

Comment: the onclick handler of your initial button can pass the id of the said button as a reference via event global object like so `onclick="openModal(event)"` then in the `function openModal(event){}` funtion you can use `event.currentTarget.id` to extract the ID.

Comment: what do you mean by `I need to get that dynamic id into this particular button attribute.`? is this about how to give a button a dynamic id? or is this about pushing the dynamic id to the modal?

Comment: here is  a snippet of what I am trying to do.
https://plnkr.co/edit/HSsMsErh6RRu7oGtHKJ1?p=preview

Comment: the 'open modal' has id=1. Once i open the modal on click, there is an Upload button in side it. Now I want this particualar button to contain the id of the 'open modal' button

Comment: @Kevin it is about pushing the dynamic id to the modal

Answer (score 0):

Open Modal box using Jquery and a class to your button

```
  $(".buttonClass").click(function(){
       $(".modal ").modal();
       var Id=$('.buttonCLass').attr('id');
       $('.modalButtonClass').attr('id',Id);

    });
```

Comment: what is .modal?

Comment: .modal is Jquery Function it will open Your  modal

Answer (score 0):

Give your button an id. (for this example you can do this different) like this:

```
<button type="button" id="myButtonId" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Upload</button>
```

After that you need to get the id of the 'open modal' button like this:

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function(){
  var yourDynamicId = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Than you need to assign this value to the input like this:

```
$('#myButtonId').html(yourDynamicId);
```

Resulting in a total of this:

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function(){
  var yourDynamicId = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#myButtonId').html(yourDynamicId);
});
```

Note: For the purpose of this answer I overwrite the button's innerHTML, you can do whatever you like to do with this.

Note 2: The HTML in your plnkr is invalid. Here is an fixed version of your HTML (already added the id to the button) [Here is the fixed plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/dpCVTHKxsbWkN6Jmmujc?p=preview)

Comment: The $('#myButtonId').html(yourDynamicId) manipulates the html, right? How do I set the id instead of html? just$('#myButtonId').id(yourDynamicId) will do?

Comment: yes the `.html()` changes the html to the specified value, as far as setting the id attribute you could use `$('#myButtonId').attr('id', yourDynamicID)`

Comment: this button's id attribute is already 'myButtonId'. I set this using the above logic and alerted out the id for thiss. it shows  'myButtonId'

Comment: `$('#myButtonId').attr('id', yourDynamicID)` overwrites the #myButtonId to #whateverYourDynamicIdIs. however this would result in having a duplicate id which is bad.

Comment: it does not overwrite the value in my case

Comment: because i made i typo :$ (last d should be lowercase)`$('#myButtonId').attr('id', yourDynamicId);`

Comment: but note that `$('#myButtonId').on('click',...` will not work as the id is changed. to fix this you can add an unique class to the button and select it with the class like this `$('.thisIsAButtonClass').on('click',...`

Comment: ah, okay, thanks a ton for the much needed help here. :)

Comment: also, is there a way to clear out the modal cache? everytime i click on the 'open modal' with the dynamic id, the id in the 'myButtonId' remains the same as the previous one.

Comment: You could instead append the modal from within the JavaScript each Time the open modal button is clicked